# Made external HDD bootable installation device by accident. How do I recover files?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, data-recovery, bootable

So I messed up big time and ran:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/linuxmint-19-cinnamon-64bit-beta.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

while having my HDD still in and it made the HDD the bootable device instead of another USB I had plugged in.

Any simple tricks to reverse this or fix it? It isn't appearing as a HDD anymore.

Comment: when you way " It isn't appearing as a HDD anymore."  how does an HDD appear in that context?

Answer (score -3):

well you've hosed the start of that disk.

repair could be tricky

if you want to recover files "photorec" will get some of your data back.

if you want to reverse that you'll probably have to start by redoing the partiton table, and you'll end up with an empty disk.

Comment: there were two questions, I missed one of them.